# Do I have to restart my phone when I'm done with adb?

Tags: android, adb

So after I'm done using adb on my Android device, do I just unplug the USB wire from the computer and restart my phone, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to restart your phone.

Using ADB doesn't inherently change anything about your phone's configuration.  Some test frameworks may do things like disable animations on the device, which you might have to reset manually in developer settings if the tests are interrupted partway through and it fails to restore the original settings.  But generally, rebooting won't help.

You can simply unplug your phone when you're done using ADB.